# Django serializer not save data to database but response is OK

Tags: python, django, rest

The serializer below don't save changes to database but JSON response from API has new correct values!
What is wrong with it?

```
class FieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Field
        fields = 'id', 'name', 'default'

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    field = FieldSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    def _save_field(self, instance):
        field = self.initial_data.pop('field', None)
        field_ids = field['id']
        field = Field.objects.get(pk=field_ids)
        instance.field = field

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(**kwargs)
        self._save_field(instance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not saving `instance` after setting the field:

```
def _save_field(self, instance):
    field = self.initial_data.pop('field', None)
    field_ids = field['id']
    field = Field.objects.get(pk=field_ids)
    instance.field = field
    instance.save()  # <-- mandatory
```

The field was properly attributed to the instance which was serialized, but not saved to the DB, that's why you saw the right response with the new values.